# O que é e para que serve OData?

Tags: terminologia, asp.net-web-api

Tenho me deperado com algumas pessoas falando sobre **`OData`**, fiz algumas pesquisas vi alguns códigos, mas não me ficou claro algumas coisas, dentre elas:

- Para que serve OData?
- Quais as vantagens e desvantagens?
- Quando usar OData?
- Quando não usar OData?

Comment: OData serve para criar e consumir APIs REST. Não acredito que haja melhor definição e documentação que a encontrada no portal oficial http://www.odata.org/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

O OData (*Open Data Protocol*) define um conjunto de práticas recomendadas para criar e consumir [APIs RESTful](https://becode.com.br/o-que-e-api-rest-e-restful/). O OData ajuda você a se concentrar na sua lógica ao criar [APIs RESTful](https://becode.com.br/o-que-e-api-rest-e-restful/) sem precisar se preocupar com as várias abordagens para definir cabeçalhos de solicitação e resposta, códigos de status, métodos HTTP, convenções de URL, tipos de mídia, formatos de carga útil, opções de consulta etc.

O crescimento exponencial de aplicativos SaaS levou a uma explosão de [APIs REST](https://becode.com.br/o-que-e-api-rest-e-restful/). Isso significa que um desenvolvedor passará a maior parte do tempo aprendendo novas APIs em vez de criar o próprio aplicativo. Para resolver esse problema, a Microsoft criou o padrão OData para criar [APIs REST](https://becode.com.br/o-que-e-api-rest-e-restful/).

> **Para que serve OData?**

O protocolo permite a criação e o consumo de [APIs REST](https://becode.com.br/o-que-e-api-rest-e-restful/), que permitem que os clientes Web publiquem e editem recursos usando URLs e definidos em um modelo de dados, usando mensagens HTTP simples. Suporta os formatos HTTP, [Atom Pub](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom) e JSON.

> **Quais as vantagens e desvantagens?**

*Vantagens:*

- Tem suporte para qualquer tipo de fonte de dados, até mesmo uma classe personalizada própria.
- Não há necessidade de criar um objeto de serviço de proxy. Então, é leve de usar.
- Você pode criar seus próprios métodos personalizados e expô-los.
- Como é leve, a interação entre servidor e cliente é rápida. Assim, apresenta um bom desempenho.
- Oferece suporte completo a [CRUD](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRUD) usando os diferentes métodos HTTP:

  - GET: obtém uma ou várias entradas.
  - POST: cria uma nova entrada.
  - PUT: atualiza uma entrada existente.
  - DELETE: remove uma entrada.

*Desvantagens:*

- Como é puramente baseado em URL, é menos seguro.
- Nem todo operador de consulta no [LINQ](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) está disponível em OData, como *filter*, *skip*, *take* etc.

> **Quando usar OData?**

À medida em que a explosão de [APIs](https://becode.com.br/o-que-e-api-rest-e-restful/) continua, cada organização expõe suas próprias [APIs REST](https://becode.com.br/o-que-e-api-rest-e-restful/)/[SOAP](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP)/[Bulk](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/bulk-data-transfer) exclusivas para o consumo de seus dados. E algumas delas também criam suas próprias linguagens de consulta exclusivas, como [ROQL](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/adapter-rightnow/using-rightnow-adapter/GUID-0D1B2623-1C65-4966-B715-12F58E0CDE9B.htm#TKRDP2710) (*Oracle Service Cloud*), [SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm) (*Salesforce*), etc. Isso dificulta que uma empresa e sua equipe de desenvolvimento possam aprender e programar em relação a todos esses recursos, com APIs diferentes.

É onde o OData é muito útil. O OData defende uma maneira padrão de implementar [APIs REST](https://becode.com.br/o-que-e-api-rest-e-restful/) que permite recursos de consulta semelhantes a SQL usando essas [APIs RESTful](https://becode.com.br/o-que-e-api-rest-e-restful/). O OData é essencialmente o SQL para a Web criado sobre os protocolos padrão - HTTP, JSON e [ATOM](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom) - enquanto aproveita o estilo de arquitetura REST.

> **Quando não usar OData?**

Observe os itens em *Desvantagens* listados no tópico "*Quais as vantagens e desvantagens?*".

---

*Referências:*

- https://www.progress.com/blogs/odata-faqs-why-should-rest-api-developers-use-odata
- https://sandippatilprogrammer.wordpress.com/2013/12/03/what-is-odata-advantages-and-disadvantages/
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Data_Protocol